# Is Mike an anarchist in *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress*?

Tags: character-analysis, politics, robert-a-heinlein, the-moon-is-a-harsh-mistress

In the later parts of Robert Heinlein's *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress*, we find out that Manny and Prof are motivated by their anarchist political beliefs.  They argue for these beliefs in the new parliment, and I think those beliefs took a big part of what motivated their active participation in the revolution.  Even in the earlier parts of the book, Manny explains some of his anarchist beliefs, but it's only in the later parts that tell how far he's willing to go to fight for them.

However, I am not sure about the motivation of Mike.  Is Mike also an anarchist by conviction?  If so, then that would have motivated him to participate in the revolution, just like it did for Manny and Prof.  But Mike didn't participate in the arguments in the parliment in the later parts of the book, or in creating the new free Lunar state in general.  This makes it more difficult to me to determine his true beliefs.

I can imagine hypothetical alternate motivations for Mike, rather than a deep conviction of anarchy.  He could have had no specific political preference, but went along with the other protagonist's plan to do something that was fun for him.  He could have felt personal sympathy with Mike and the Prof and supported them for that reason.  He could have just found the old government and the Warden so annoying or evil that he went through with the revolution to replace that, even if he didn't know what new government he wanted.  He could even have thought himself more powerful than the other characters (it would be a reasonable assumption), and was planning on a different endgame than an anarchist Luna, but still found the revolution a good starting strategy for whatever his goals were.

Thus, my question is, what is Mike's motivation for participating in the revolution?  In particular, what are his political or moral beliefs, and is he a convinced anarchist?  Note that I am not asking about Heinlein's own political beliefs.  That's a separate question that's partly covered by [“How anticommunist was Robert Heinlein?” (on Sci Fi SE)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/54547/4918)

As usual, I'd like an answer supported by the book, or possibly by interviews with *Heinlein* or other books he wrote.